# To check if a given string is SuperAscii or Not - java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string

The problem goes like this:

#### If a is assigned the value 1, b=2,c=3,...z=26, check if a given string is a Super Ascii String or not. A string is said to be a Super Ascii String, if the number of times a character is repeated matches its value. The string must be only in lowercase letters

Eg. abbccc is super ascii because a=1,b=2,c=3. Similarly, bab, "bb a ccc"

This is my attempt in solving the problem

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SuperAsciiNew
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string : ");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        char[] inputArray = input.replaceAll("\\s+","").toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(inputArray);
        String customInput = new String(inputArray);
        char currentChar = customInput.charAt(0);
        int increment=0;
        Map<Character, Integer> characterMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        char a='a';
        boolean superascii = true;
        for(int i=1;a<='z';i++,a++)
            characterMap.put(new Character(a), new Integer(i));
        while(increment<=customInput.length())
        {
            int nooftimes = customInput.lastIndexOf(currentChar) - customInput.indexOf(currentChar) + 1;
            if(characterMap.get(currentChar) == nooftimes)
            {
                System.out.println("The character "+currentChar+" is repeated "+nooftimes);
                increment += nooftimes;
                currentChar = customInput.charAt(increment); 
            }
            else
            {
                superascii = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(superascii == true)
            System.out.println("The given string "+input+" is a Super Ascii string");
        else
            System.out.println("The given string "+input+" is not a Super Ascii string");

    }
}
```

Here, first I am removing spaces (if any), sorting the string. Then, I find the first character in the string, what is its value and how many times is it repeated. If these two values are not equal then the loop is broken else, the number of times the character is repeated is incremented in increment variable and the next character is found.

The output I get for various test cases:

```
 java SuperAsciiNew 
Enter a string : abb ccc
The character a is repeated 1
The character b is repeated 2
The character c is repeated 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at SuperAsciiNew.main(SuperAsciiNew.java:30)

java SuperAsciiNew 
Enter a string : bab 
The character a is repeated 1
The character b is repeated 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at SuperAsciiNew.main(SuperAsciiNew.java:30)

java SuperAsciiNew 
Enter a string : hello world
The given string hello world is not a Super Ascii string
```

When the string "hello world" is given, the output is generated without any exceptions. What is the issue here?

I have one more doubt in Java:

#### What is the difference between importing individual classes like java.util.Scanner and importing the package as whole java.util.*? Are there any performance issues? What I feel is, the second one might consume more memory while the first, the system has to search the appropriate class and include it. Am I  right in my thinking?

Comment: The two way of importing have no different effect on the code generated. In the early time of java, `*`  was a bit more popular, as other languages did not have such fine grained import. Nowadays it is considered good style to list all classes, and IDE help with that with automatic imports.

Comment: Homework?Homework?Homework!!!!

Comment: @AlexandreSantos it isn't homework. I am trying to improve my coding skills. I was stuck up and hence posted it. Am I violating the rules of SO?

Comment: Nah, just yanking your chain. This kind of code is for homework. Post away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for a character one too many times. 
Use the following condition:

```
while(increment<=customInput.length()-1)
```

instead of:

```
while(increment<=customInput.length())
```

Edit: the reason you are not getting the error on "hello world" is because it fails before reaching that extra char, thus not throwing an exception.

Comment: You can always add a break condition after `increment += nooftimes;`: `if((increment)>=customInput.length()) { break; }`